# Creating a trigger to update one table's row based on another update from a different table's row

Tags: mysql

So, I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `services` (
  `services_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_num` INT NOT NULL,
  `health_and_wellness` INT NOT NULL,
  `tutoring` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`services_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `services_id_UNIQUE` (`services_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_services_healthandwell_idx` (`health_and_wellness` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_services_tutoring_idx` (`tutoring` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_services_tutoring`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tutoring`)
    REFERENCES `tutoring` (`tutoring_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_services_healthandwell`
    FOREIGN KEY (`health_and_wellness`)
    REFERENCES `health and wellness` (`health_and_wellness_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tutoring` (
  `tutoring_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` INT NOT NULL,
  `staff_members` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tutoring_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `tutoring_id_UNIQUE` (`tutoring_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_tutoring_subject_idx` (`subject` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tutoring_subject`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subject`)
    REFERENCES `subjects` (`subject_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I want to create a trigger that updates services.staff_num whenever tutoring.staff_members is updated.. I've tried a couple different triggers, but each time nothing happens or I get an error.. My latest attempt was this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStaffNum AFTER UPDATE ON collegedb.tutoring FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE services
        SET services.staff_num = services.staff_num + tutoring.staff_members; 
END;
```

Which of course would be too simple too work, heh. Anyone have any suggestions on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your design you are looking for this

only if a staff_members then update the services rows that refer to that tutoring entry, that was changed.

I added also to remove the old Staff_Memebers as it only updates when that value has changed.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStaffNum AFTER UPDATE ON collegedb.tutoring FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (OLD.staff_members <> NEW.staff_members) THEN
            UPDATE services
            SET services.staff_num = services.staff_num - OLD.staff_members + NEW.staff_members
            WHERE tutoring = NEW.tutoring_id; 
        END IF;
END;
```